# Using request_started signal for a particular request

Tags: python, django, django-signals

Is it possible to restrict the `request_started` signal to run for a particular request? I have browsed around the web and only seem to find it being triggered for each request that is made.

Comment: short answer, **No**

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking here, or why you would want to do that. Perhaps if you explain your use case a bit more someone can offer a workable alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter based on the information found in `environ`. This is the same information that is used to create the request object. However, the signal itself is sent before the request is even created.

```
def callback(sender, environ, **kwargs):
    if environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/your/url':
        print('Your code here')


request_started.connect(callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't get request_started triggered only for a particular request, but you can "early exit" from the signal handler for other.

You can use the `PATH_INFO` variable and do "standard Django request processing stuff" for route parsing and getting more info about the application, view & etc executing in the request.

There is a working example (for my test project env & urls of course).

```
from django.core.signals import request_started
from django.urls import resolve, Resolver404


def callback(sender, environ, **kwargs):
    if not 'PATH_INFO' in environ:
        return

    path = environ['PATH_INFO']
    try:
        match = resolve(path)
    except Resolver404:
        return

    if match.url_name == 'stores_storecategory_history':
        from pprint import pprint
        pprint(match.__dict__)


request_started.connect(callback)
```

Which is executed only on the url route pattern and I can do whatever I want in the handler.

```
web_1            | {'_func_path': 'reversion.admin.history_view',
web_1            |  'app_name': 'admin',
web_1            |  'app_names': ['admin'],
web_1            |  'args': (),
web_1            |  'func': <function VersionAdmin.history_view at 0x7f522292b9d0>,
web_1            |  'kwargs': {'object_id': '1586'},
web_1            |  'namespace': 'admin',
web_1            |  'namespaces': ['admin'],
web_1            |  'route': 'admin/stores/storecategory/<path:object_id>/history/',
web_1            |  'url_name': 'stores_storecategory_history',
web_1            |  'view_name': 'admin:stores_storecategory_history'}
```